# SQLite Select command missing data 1% of the time

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlite

I'm having an issue with some of my SQLite code, 99% of the time the below code works perfectly, but the 1% it doesn't work is leaving me totally baffled.

At times I need to make a copy of all the records in one of my tables to another database, so I run the below code.

```
    Dim DataSet As New DataSet
    Dim DataAdapter As SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter
    DataAdapter = New SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT ALL * FROM " & tableName, SQLconnect) 'No Where clause, so we are grabbing ALL the records in the table'
    DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, tableName)

    Dim ParamList As New Hashtable
    Dim Table As DataTable = DataSet.Tables(tableName) 'tableName is a string sent to the sub where this code is located'
    Dim Row As DataRow = Nothing
    If Table.Rows.Count > 0 Then 'Skip if there are no records to copy'
        Row = Table.Rows(0)
        Dim InsertString As String = ""
        For n As Integer = 0 To Table.Rows.Count - 1
            ParamList.Clear()
            InsertString = "INSERT INTO " & tableName & " VALUES("
            For i As Integer = 0 To Table.Columns.Count - 1
                InsertString = InsertString & "@" & Table.Columns(i).ColumnName
                If i <> Table.Columns.Count - 1 Then InsertString = InsertString & ", "
                ParamList.Add("@" & Table.Columns(i).ColumnName, Table.Rows(n).Item(i))
            Next
            InsertString = InsertString & ")"
            RunSQLiteCode(InsertString, , DBConnectionNumber, ParamList) 'This runs the SQLite query we just assembled above'
        Next
    End If
```

Normally this code works perfectly. But 1% of the time, for some reason not all of the records are getting copied over. Most recently for example I had 23,800 records in a table to copy over, but only 19,567 of them actually made it over to the other database.

Whatever is causing this issue, it seems much more likely to happen when I have thousands of records in a table, though I have had this problem occur when copying as few 43 records, only 15 of them made it over.

There's no reliable way to duplicate this error, which is only making debugging it even more difficult. Even after this issue pops up, if I try doing the exact same steps 10+ times I can't get it to happen again. I've never gotten this error to occur when I'm using break points so that I can investigate it closer.

Nothing else in my code is even touching the databases, or connections to the databases while this code is run either. I haven't had any luck searching the web, or looking very closely at my code for something that could be messing it up and causing records to be forgotten.

I know I didn't accidentally delete all the missing records when this occurs either, because if I look at the table that I'm copying the records from, all the missing records are still there.

So, bottom line, I'm stumped, what could be causing this problem?

**Edit:** I think I've made some progress at figuring out how to duplicate this issue. It seems if I hover my mouse over the menu item that triggers this event, and click multiple times very rapidly on my mouse, this bug happens about 2/3's of the time.

Now I'm even more baffled how this isn't causing my program to either crash or hit a catch in a try catch statement if attempting to run my click events multiple times is causing this issue.

Comment: You might want to try logging the SQL statements (at least until you can debug this issue) to a text file prior to execution.  That way the next time it happens you can try to rule out the SQL Statement that gets generated and then focus on the RunSQLLiteCode() method or the DB itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more playing around with my code and researching the problem, I'm certain that the issue is caused by double clicking my mouse rapidly when triggering this code.

I'm still not entirely sure how SQLite queries are causing the errors I get, but somehow double clicking fast enough on the button to trigger this code makes it run multiple times, which I'm guessing interrupts my SELECT loop because I'm reusing that data connection before I finish with it.

I added a few lines of code at the very beginning of the click event that triggers all this to run.

```
    Dim oldState As Boolean = Enabled
    Enabled = False
    If oldState = False Then Exit Sub
```

The above code seems to fix the double clicking problem by disabling the entire form while the code is running, and causing any extra clicks that run the sub twice to exit the sub immediately. Without the above code I can get this bug to occur about 2/3's of the time by clicking fast enough. With the above code I haven't been able to get the error to occur once after dozens of attempts.